# WHY Qt reports **_resource_res.o Error 1?

Tags: c++, qt

I was using Qt Creator on my Windows11 virtual machine,and I cloned my team's repository from github.I did no changes to it at all, and when I tried to build it reports error.

I asked my teammates to try building it, and they all finished the build without any problem. Confusingly I uninstalled the Qt and install it again. This time it works, but when I pulled the latest version with git, It reports the error again.

```
`:-1: error: [Makefile.Debug:102: debug/ChineseCheckers_resource_res.o] Error 1`
```

I wonder what on earth was wrong.

More info:

My teammates are using windows11 too. Their Qt Creator reports no error.
I have tried to delete `build-ChineseCheckers-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_MinGW_64_bit-Debug` folder, or simply delete `ChineseCheckers.pro.user`, but none of these worked.

The files are stored in an USB device.

It reports error after I pulled from github and build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself. I had a missing resource file: "logo.ico". It seems that my teammates forget to upload that image, so it can be built on their machine, but mine failed. :/

Besides, I moved the file from USB device to the desktop, but I think that's not the point. Anyway, at least one of these works.

Comment: Started the last comment before I seen your answer. Good you fixed it, sorry for any confusion regarding my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the Qt generated files, including hidden files, i.e., .uics, .objs, .mocs from the project directory.

Don't delete your project's .pro file, but delete all Qt generated hidden files and directories. I had similar issues and found that rebuilding the project completely put things back in sync.

Comment: Sorry, but I wonder where the hidden files you've mentioned are stored. I can only find one hidden .git folder. I've tried to delete the genernated file in `build-ChineseCheckers-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_MinGW_64_bit-Debug`, but nothing happened.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. If the Qt generated file aren't present, they're not the problem. Try rebuilding the resource .o (object file) from scratch. Make sure you're removing the old.